# Windows Phone - how to handle two image sets?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, serialization, settings

I am writing an app, where I am using two image sets - white and black. It depends on the background that user is currently using in whole OS. 
(personally I prefer black background, however I know people, who are desperate do use white)

So. I created two folders: `/Images/Dark` and `/Images/Light` containing the same file names, the only difference is the color of the image (White in Dark and Black in Light).
I works like this: whenever I bind Image Source into something I check my `String appBackground;` which is set into Light or Dark, and then I create the rest of the path. Like this:

`this.imageSource = getIconPath((App.Current as App).appBackground) + this.name + ".png";`

This works just fine. The problem is, when I want to save for example a list of objects to which image binds its source, to a file. It's because I serialize a String, which is fixed into one path. So, I may have a list of items with white icons, but when I change my background into white - the icons remain the same.

My idea was, to save only the last, file name part. (`this.name+".png"`) and then somehow, dynamically glue it into appBackground. The problem is: I don't really know how to do that properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use two sets of bitmap images, then use rather MVVM approach - fixed reference to image source property in your ViewModel, that is returning either the black or white image based on the current system background.
I use it like this:

```cs
public string SmsImg
{
    get { return AppHelper.IsBlackTheme ? "/Images/appbar.send.white.png" : "/Images/appbar.send.black.png"; }
}
```

and the implementation of IsBlackTheme:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Return true if pohone uses Black color theme.
/// </summary>
public static bool IsBlackTheme
{
    get
    {
        if (!isBlackTheme.HasValue)
        {
            SolidColorBrush bg = Application.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
            isBlackTheme = bg != null && bg.Color == Colors.Black;
        }
        return isBlackTheme.Value;
    }
}
private static bool? isBlackTheme;
```

Comment: I dont really know if this approach works for me.
Implrementing "is it black?" is quite easy. However, in my code i have something like that:

There is a list of my objects. Every object has two fields: `name` and `imgSource`. (imgSource is created from name inside of that class. We end up with ex. `String ABC` and `String Image/Light/ABC.png`. In XAML I bind my Listbox into that list, and in datatemplate I bind `name` into texblock and `imgSource` into Image.

The problem is, that list (the Source of Listbox) is loaded from memory. So inside, there are wrong image sources...

Comment: You should not serialize the image paths directly, but rather serialize the pure objects, or only object names and get the image paths dynamically whenever you need to display the image.